# Is there a word for "automatic" with negative connotations?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Often anything that is **automatic** is perceived to be good. But what if I want to make it sound bad? Can I use a different word or phrase?

As context and an example, we're in a dispute with a company that has a policy of **automatically** renewing subscriptions without any warning or notification that the subscription is up for renewal.

Answer (score 39):

[Mechanically](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/mechanically)

> Without thought or spontaneity; automatically.
> *‘the words are repeated mechanically’*

Comment: This is *the* perfect answer. It might not be the best solution to the OP's problem, but it has exactly the same meaning as "automatic" (performed "by" or "as if by" a machine) and it has negative connotations.

Answer (score 31):

[**blindly**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/blindly) (adj.)

- 2. Without understanding or using one's judgement; unthinkingly. *‘don't blindly accept dogma as justification’*

From that definiton, "**unthinkingly**" would also fit your purposes.  If your complaint is primarily that there was no notice, "**silently**" fits the bill, but doesn't convey the "without thought" part.  British English speakers sometimes use "**blithely**" to describe unthinking actions, but it's rare in American English.

To convey your frustration that the action was not one you were given a chance to agree to, consider

**[Unilaterally](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/unilaterally)** (adj.)

- undertaken or done by or on behalf of one side, party, or faction only; not mutual

However, using a single word will reduce the emphasis on that aspect of your complaint. If there's a particular aspect of behaviour that you are unhappy with, it's usually better to state it in full. In your example, try this:

- automatically renewed this subscription **without first obtaining our consent**.

This also explains the behaviour you were expecting. (You can of course replace "automatically" with any of the suggested adjectives)

Comment: I think blindly best fits the titles question, but silently best fits the example provided (as far as single word options) - but I wonder which is the real question

Answer (score 8):

1. **peremptorily**

> in a way that expects to be obeyed immediately and without any
> questions.
> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/peremptorily

2. **robotically**

> Then he was mocked for robotically repeating the same answer during a
> television interview. Times, Sunday Times (2011)
> https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/robotically

Answer (score 5):

**Knee-jerk** is defined by [lexico.com](https://www.lexico.com/definition/knee-jerk) as

> (of a response) automatic and unthinking.

Comment: Came here to say this. Also "reflexive" or, in some cases, "reactionary".

Answer (score 4):

[Compulsive](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/compulsive) is a reasonable fit here.

It means that something is done due to an irresistible urge or force rather than a conscious desire.

"Your policy regarding compulsive renewal is unjust..."

Answer (score 3):

I think [**rote**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rote) does well here.

From Merriam-Webster

**rote**
1: the use of memory usually with little intelligence
learn by rote
2: mechanical or unthinking routine or repetition
a joyless sense of order, rote, and commercial hustle
— L. L. King

Answer (score 2):

Doing something "on auto-pilot" can have a negative connotation. Doesn't exactly apply to the auto-renewal example, but "going through your day on auto-pilot" is a bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

Performing an action like a drone. Drone like, mindless and without any thoughts.

**Edit**
Adding supporting reference as suggested by TCooper

Definition 2 of [dronelike](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dronelike) from Wiktionary, which is *a synonym of* **mechanical**

Definition 3.1 of [drone](https://lexico.com/en/definition/drone) from Lexico.com

In the latter, a usage example is
*‘Oh, you're right, they do sound like mindless drones when they greet you, Toni!’*

Comment: A *drone*? As in, a "stingless male bee", a "parasite" or "an unmanned aircraft"? I don't see how any of those could fit.

Comment: @eric Parasite? What is the connection? Drone as in preprogrammed, acting according to given instruction set with hardly any automation or minimal decision making.

Comment: That was my point, I don't see any connection to the question either. I merely listed the definitions I found in Merriam-Webster. Do you have any link to a definition of "drone" which could fit?

Comment: While I agree with @EricDuminil - I can't find a published definition that fits - I knew exactly what you meant and your answer fit well (at least for me) in this context. While it may not be an official use, I think it falls into popular use. Whether that's acceptable on this site... For why it fits the context to me, see definition 3.1 https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/drone and definition 2 https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dronelike, and also the synonym 'mechanical' linked on the page - these act in a mindless way, automatically. To me the mindlessness is the negative

Comment: @TCooper this answer could be improved by editing in the definition/source in your comment

Answer (score 1):

I like

- tacit

And I prefer

- senseless / mindless

over "blindly" because I don't see a need to conflate sightedness with thoughtfulness.

Answer (score 1):

I think **Programmed** does bear a negative connotation when applied to humans.
Similar use can be found [here](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/swim-in-denial/201605/programmed-life)

Another term **Hardwired** may also convey similar yet not exactly same meanings

Answer (score 1):

In the same spirit as one of the answers above, there is also [*mechanistically*](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/mechanistically), which I think is slightly more pejorative than *mechanically*.

Comment: You beat me to it!

Answer (score -1):

**Unbidden**

> not invited or wanted

Even though it isn't exactly the same as **automatically**, it could be used as a negative connotation of the same to signify that the action was performed without consideration and/or explicit request and was perceived negatively because of it's undesirability.

Answer (score -2):

OED:

> **pre-emptive**, adj. and n.

> 3. Military. Of an offensive strategy or action: intended to forestall an enemy attack; frequently in pre-emptive strike (now frequently figurative).

In its figurative sense it carries the nuance of an action taken suddenly in anticipation of, and to counter, the third party's possible action:

> OECD Economic Surveys: Mexico 2007 - Page 11 "The bank responded with a pre-emptive move by raising its interest rate in April, in order to prevent the upturn in inflation from feeding into inflation expectations."

In your context, "pre-emptive" would be have the nuance of "reprehensible."

Answer (score -2):

How about **covert** autopayments? From Lexico:

> **[covert](https://www.lexico.com/definition/covert)**: Not openly acknowledged or displayed.

When a company charges you automatically, especially for a long period of time, for services you no longer use, and it does so without letting you know this is the case, e.g., by sending you regular itemized bills or querying you re your extended non-use of the service, they are not openly acknowledging or displaying that they're continuing to charge you. I'd call these **covert** autopayments.

**Surreptitious** autopayments would also work (see Conrado's comment on your question). From Lexico:

> **[surreptitious](https://www.lexico.com/definition/surreptitious)**: Kept secret, especially because it would not be approved of.

While one could argue that such autopayments are not entirely secret, the automatic charging policies of some companies certainly demonstrate a major, if not intentional, lack of transparency.

While I am a firm believer in "Caveat emptor," I considered my Netflix experience (see my comment on your question) to be an **unscrupulous** business practice (see Jim's comment on your question). From Lexico:

> **[unscrupulous](https://www.lexico.com/definition/unscrupulous)**: Having or showing no moral principles; not honest or fair.

Comment: I don't think that these 3 words are alternatives for, or imply, "automatic(ally)"

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt  Thanks. Fair enough, but with autopayment they do. OP requested single words or phrases. Many of the single words suggested in other answers don't work by themselves either.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Note also that the question says this: "As context and an example, we're in a dispute with a company that has a policy of automatically renewing subscriptions without any warning or notification that the subscription is up for renewal." That's what I was addressing in my answer.

Answer (score -2):

### repetitive

This word is usually used with negative meaning.

"Repetitive work tires the worker."

"Repetitive strain injury"

It does not convey the meaning of "automatic" in the sense that something happens without human intervention, but the context could convey that.

"The repetitive confirmation dialogues from the software annoy me."

---

Note: I am aware that "repetitive" is not a synonym for "automatic". It might fit the bill in a context where the automatic nature is implicit.

Answer (score -3):

This is what the question says (emphasis mine):

> a policy of automatically renewing subscriptions without any warning or notification that the subscription is **up** for renewal.

This means that you have already agreed that there will be an automatic renewal. There isn't anything shady going on that a renewal happens without you having known that would be the case.

Therefore, the emphasis is on the renewal itself, rather than the motivations of the company behind it.

Some companies do provide advance notice that something is about to be renewed. It gives you a chance to cancel your subscript if you wish. Without that advance notice, you can have forgotten about it and miss the chance to cancel (assuming you want to).

How could the quality of the this automatic renewal be expressed? It is  [**abrupt**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abrupt):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1 a** : characterized by or involving action or change without preparation or warning : sudden and unexpected
>       // came to an *abrupt* stop
>       // an *abrupt* turn
>       // an *abrupt* decision to retire
> **1 b** : rudely or unceremoniously curt
>       // She has an *abrupt* manner.
>       // an *abrupt* reply
> **1 c** : lacking smoothness or continuity
>       // an *abrupt* transition

A possible sentence used to describe the situation in the question is the following:

> Without a friendly reminder ahead of time, we find your automatic renewals to be *abrupt*.

Anything that is *abrupt* has a negative connotation. As in the definition itself, it is sudden, unexpected, rude, curt, and lacking advance notice.

Comment: The question was asking for a synonym for the word automatic with a more negative connotation. This example still uses the word and just tries to frame the word as negative by adding a qualifier.